# How to render picture-in-picture effect with libGDX camera

Tags: libgdx, rendering, camera, viewport

libGDX cameras are mostly used for layered rendering with different "world unit size," but I wonder is there a way of showing the view of for example a libGDX Orthographic camera in the corner of screen - lets say showing what a drone's camera sees from ground?

Here's an example:

[image: Image of plane on a runway, with a smaller picture-in-picture view of the same in the corner]

How can I achieve such effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render the drones view to a `FrameBuffer`, and then draw that `FrameBuffer` onto your main screen.

This is often referred to as *render to texture*.

[FrameBuffers in libGDX](https://libgdx.com/wiki/graphics/opengl-utils/frame-buffer-objects)

Comment: Oh thanks for the answer @bornander. If I'm right  I should draw the game twice ;once with the drone camera onto a Frame buffer and then draw that frame buffer on the actual game camera? I'll try this method and inform you the results.

Comment: Yes @M-Avoid, that is what I am suggesting. Are you doing 2D or 3D? I might find the time to create an example.

Comment: I'm sorry for this late reply; I'm trying to do 2d, did the thing and got some nice results as needed,but I may understand the concept for 3d aswell thank you for your effort